# How to authenticate a client's login information through MongoDB & Restheart

Tags: mongodb, authentication, restheart

I am working on the RestAPI for my capstone project, however I am stuck at a particular part. I have to have the back end server (mongoDB) authenticate the client's login information (email / password) whether if they inputted the correct information or not. However currently, the client is an object in a collection since I am creating the client's account through restheart. In the object is the information such as the email, password, and other attributes that are needed for my project. Is there a way to authenticate the email and password within that object to see whether it is correct or not thus letting the client move on through that stage?

Or would I have to specifically make users (not objects)???

Answer (score 0):

RESTHeart provides pluggable authentication and authorization: the configurable Identity Manager and Access Manager are responsible of identify the client and check permissions respectively.

RESTHeart provides two Identity Managers, *SimpleFileIdentityManager* that is based on a configuration file (where you specify ids, passwords and roles) and *DbIdentityManager* that uses a mongodb collection to store ids, passwords and roles. It also provides *SimpleAccessManager*, where permissions are defined in a configuration file.

It is easy to also develop custom IDMs and AMs to fit special needs.

See [enable and configure security](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/IgDM), [how clients authenticate](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/JgDM) , [custom identity manager](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/HADM) and [custom access manager](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/HgDM) in the documentation for more information.

If you use the DB Based Identity Manager, make sure to filter out passwords from the response. This can be easily achieved with the *filterProperties* [tranformer](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/i4CM)